# DataGridColumn Header content WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, datagrid, datatemplate, wpfdatagrid

I want to localize a presentation and I'm having a brain freeze on this one. I'm using a markup extension, so instead of having this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding Number}" Width="60" CellStyle="{StaticResource NumberStyle}" />
```

I want this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{Resx Key=Header_Number}" Binding="{Binding Number}" Width="60" CellStyle="{StaticResource NumberStyle}" />
```

where the markup, which is well tested, will just return the right text for the current culture. But it isn't working. I assume I need either a HeaderStyle or HeaderTemplate but...

What is the fix?

Cheers,
Berryl

## EDIT

By isn't working I mean it isn't returning the text "Number" while in English, and instead returning a default value (ie, "#Header_Number).

By *is* working, I mean that

```
    <Label FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Resx Key=Label_Amount}"/>
```

returns "Amount" while in English.

## FINAL EDIT

My bad, this is really more a result of the fact that WPF data grid columns to not inherit the DataContext of their parent.

The markup extension has a ResxName property which I like to set once for the entire window:

```
    resx:ResxProperty.Name="NMoneys.Presentation.Resources.AllocatorView"
    Title="{Resx Key=Window_Title}"
```

But since the headers in the data grid aren't part of the visual tree (although it sure seems they should be!), I have to specifically put the name of the Resx again, as in

```
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=NMoneys.Presentation.Resources.AllocatorView, Key=ColumnHeader_Number}" Binding="{Binding Number}" Width="60" CellStyle="{StaticResource NumberStyle}" />
```

I've run into this before and seen a few techniques to forward the DC, but in this case it isn't worth the bother.

Cheers,
Berryl

Comment: `isn't working` is terribly specific...

Comment: @H.B. Let me know if iteration# 2 brings the problem into focus better

Comment: That's a little more info, but don't you think there's just something wrong with the extension? How about posting its code?

Comment: Please either post or proper answer and accept it or delete the question if you think it isn't helpful, which might be rather likely.

Comment: I actually think it is rather helpful, which is why I didn't delete it, and won't. Will leave it open for another day to see if anyone else has a different take on an answer involving DataGrid data context forwarding; or make it an accepted answer if not. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have models representating your entities. What I've done is used data annotations. Here is the example. Edit: Provided MVVM classes with screenshots

**Model**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

using Silverlight.Infrastructure.Properties;

namespace Silverlight.Infrastructure.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources), Name = "CustomerIdHeader")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        // There must be an entry CustomerNameHeader in the resources else it 
        // will throw an exception
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources), Name = "CustomerNameHeader")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The header content will then automatically bind to the display of the property.

**ViewModel**

```
using Silverlight.Infrastructure.Models

namespace Silverlight.ModuleA.ViewModels
{
    //Prism namespaces
    public class CustomerViewModel : NotificationObject
    {
        public CustomerViewModel()
        {   
            // service for my customers.
            CustomeService customerService = new CustomerService();
            Customers = customerService.GetCustomers()
        }   

        public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers {get;set;}
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <data:DataGrid x:Name="CustomerGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                    <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Surname, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Company, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </data:DataGrid.Columns>
            </data:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image: The DataGrid in the program!]

And then the resources in the typeof(StringLibrary)

[image: Resource File]

As you can see the Name of the display is equal to the ResourceKey in the resources file. I came up with the annotations first when about 2-3 weeks ago when I was developing and testing with XML. But things like AutoMapper can map your objects to pocos like these or you can even Use WCF RIA services and you can have similiar annotations. WCF RIA is actually the one who is using them, but I just use them in a different way.

There might be a few tricks here and there to accomplish this. But when you do, you really get an easy solution.

I hope I've provided enough information.

Comment: That is definitely one I haven't seen before, although not sure I get it. Can I see what your VM code (assuming your using MVVM) and XAML looks like? Cheers

Comment: @Berryl I've added the information you asked for. Let me know if you want to know something more. I can even give you the project if you want cause it is just a learning project anyway trying different things with PRISM and MVVM.